# Run function after an observable variable is initialized

Tags: angular, typescript, socket.io, rxjs, observable

I'm setting up a chat application with socket.io in Angular. I'm having problem to run a code/function right after an observable variable is initialized via subscription. That specific code after initializing should scroll down to the latest message, but it triggers too early.

I think the problem is because the variable `chatList` below didn't have enough time to get the list of messages.

Using `setTimeout(() => {/*scroll function here*/}, 1);` works, but it is not ideal at all.

```
this.getMessages()
  .subscribe((chat: string[]) => {
    this.chatList$ = chat;

    //I want the code below to run once the code above is fully Initialized.
     this.conversationList.nativeElement.scrollTop = this.conversationList.nativeElement.scrollHeight;
  });
```

What's the proper way to run a code/function once the observable is completed?

Comment: Do you mean that you want the UI to use the `this.chatList$` and create all the DOM, and THEN you call another function? Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Using the dollar sign like that `this.chatList$` conventionally means that the variable is an Observable, so I think it is weird that you are doing that.

More importantly, I don't understand what you are asking, could you add the relevant template code?

Comment: This might sound dumb, but are are you scrolling immediately after page load? If you want the user to see something immediately, why not put it at the top of the page and then sit back and let the page render naturally and avoiding scrolling altogether?

Comment: @frosty Yes that's excatly how I meant. When you put it that way, it seems like the issue actually lies at DOM not rendered in time?

Comment: @KeenanDiggs I see, thanks for clarifying. I shouldn't use a dollar sign here. 
**Template code to render the chatList:** `<div *ngFor="let item of chatList">` (removed dollar sign)

Comment: @KeenanDiggs To answer your second comment: I know it's not optimal, it's just for the sake of learning. I believe now it's because of DOM not being rendered in time by ngFor.

Answer (score 0):

Use `MutationObserver` to watch the parent node that contains your child list. Then use `subject` to emit from the callback to signal the list is ready for scroll to happen. Theoretically it should work

```
this.childReady=new Subject()
// replace the dom select with your angular viewChild nativeElement
var targetNode = document.getElementById('some-id');

// Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
var config = {childList: true };

// Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
var callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
        if (mutation.type == 'childList') {
              this.childReady.next(true)
        }
};

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

// Start observing the target node for configured mutations
observer.observe(targetNode, config);

this.getMessages().pipe(
  tap((chat: string[]) => {
    this.chatList$ = chat;
   }),
   switchMap(()=>this.childReady())
).subscribe(()=>{
     this.conversationList.nativeElement.scrollTop = this.conversationList.nativeElement.scrollHeight;

})
```